# How to get the type of the current window in vim

Tags: vim, window, buffer

I'm using a hotkey for switching buffers and I have the problem that some windows are drawn in the main window when I'm switching through the buffers.

I was able to disable the mappings for NERDTree, the Quickfix window and Tagbar window but I always need the window name in order to achieve this with an autocommand. Finding the window name mostly requires reading through a lot of help files or even plugin sources and this is very time consuming :D

For example I use this for the quickfix window:

```
augroup qf
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType qf set nobuflisted
augroup END
```

Is there an easier way to get the name of the current window?

Comment: You can also check if `&buftype` is empty ("normal" buffers) or not (special buffers), and just switch between the normal ones. Don't know what NERDTree or Tagbar set their buffers as, but it wouldn't surprise me if their type is 'nofile' or something similar.

Comment: This is also interesting, thank you for mentioning this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Buffer name: `:echo @%`. File type: `:echo &ft`. Buffer number: `echo bufnr(@%)`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure you are talking about vim's **window** or **buffer**.

> Is there an easier way to get the name of the current window?

vim window has winnr, you can get it by calling function `winnr()`, same for buffer nr, get current buffer number: `bufnr('%')`, and to get current buffer name (the file name) `bufname('%')`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The functions you meantioned are good for retrieving information in scripts but I need to know filetype of the buffer. I didn't know that the filetype is the information I need until I read the answer above :D